# Join two arrays in javascript where a matching index is found

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two separate arrays that are passed via AJAX.
The first is called cartArray and contains data related to a product being added to cart, and console.log shows it contains this.

```
max_allowed: 10
product_id: 4202
product_name: "34 inch Gold Number 1 Foil Balloon (1)"
qty: 3
```

The second is called cartqtyArray and is a count of what current cart quantity is before the add to cart action takes place. console.log shows it contains this.

```
0: {product_id: 4202, basket_qty: 2}
1: {product_id: 4203, basket_qty: 10}
2: {product_id: 0, basket_qty: 0}
3: {product_id: 0, basket_qty: 0}
4: {product_id: 0, basket_qty: 0}
5: {product_id: 0, basket_qty: 0}
6: {product_id: 0, basket_qty: 0}
7: {product_id: 0, basket_qty: 0}
8: {product_id: 0, basket_qty: 0}
9: {product_id: 0, basket_qty: 0}
10: {product_id: 0, basket_qty: 0}
```

What I need to do is combine the two arrays, matching the product_id if it exists in cartArray.
Any where there isn't a matching product_id can be discarded.

So ultimately I would end up with a new array like

```
max_allowed: 10
product_id: 4202
product_name: "34 inch Gold Number 1 Foil Balloon (1)"
qty: 3
basket_qty: 2
```

I looked at using map, but all the examples seemed to be using an array structure like

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4],
b = [34, 54, 54, 43],
```

which isn't representative of the type of arrays I have.

Some pointers on what function is available to do what I need would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your usage of the term "array" is rather confusing here, because what you show for `cartArray` and the expected output look like objects, key-value pairs separated by colons. You may be coming from PHP where associative arrays and sequential integer arrays are the same thing. In JS, arrays do not have key-value pairs. Could you post what these objects/arrays/whatever actually are in valid JS code? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, I work mostly in php, so perhaps my terminology is not accurate. cartArray and cartqtyArray are both passed PHP arrays passed via AJAX using datatype: 'json' and are assigned vars using cartArray = data.cart; and cartqtyArray = data.cartqty;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the desired result.

```js
const cartArray = [{
  max_allowed: 10,
  product_id: 4202,
  product_name: "34 inch Gold Number 1 Foil Balloon (1)",
  qty: 3,
}, {
  max_allowed: 10,
  product_id: 7,
  product_name: "34 inch Gold Number 1 Foil Balloon (1)",
  qty: 3,
}];

const cartqtyArray = [{
    product_id: 4202,
    basket_qty: 2
  },
  {
    product_id: 4203,
    basket_qty: 10
  },
  {
    product_id: 0,
    basket_qty: 0
  },
  {
    product_id: 0,
    basket_qty: 0
  },
  {
    product_id: 0,
    basket_qty: 0
  },
  {
    product_id: 0,
    basket_qty: 0
  },
  {
    product_id: 0,
    basket_qty: 0
  },
  {
    product_id: 0,
    basket_qty: 0
  },
  {
    product_id: 0,
    basket_qty: 0
  },
  {
    product_id: 0,
    basket_qty: 0
  },
  {
    product_id: 0,
    basket_qty: 0
  },
];

const result = cartArray.reduce((acc, cart) => {
  const cartItemInCartQty = cartqtyArray.find(
    (x) => x.product_id === cart.product_id
  );
  if (cartItemInCartQty) {
    acc.push({ ...cart,
      ...cartItemInCartQty
    });
  } else {
    acc.push(cart)
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I thought this was the perfect solution, and it was until I realised I hadn't considered a certain scenario.
If a product_id doesn't exist in cartqtyArray (because it doesn't exist in the cart yet) that product_id and its associated data are removed from the results. Is it possible to not drop anything from cartArray, only unrequired data from cartqtyArray?

Comment: updated code @Steph3071. IS this what you want

Comment: Added an object with id `7` that is not present in the `cartqtyArray ` array but it still there in result.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it needs to work. Thanks for the info on reduce, find, and Object destructuring. I'll do some test pieces with those so I can widen my knowledge for future use.

Comment: eager to please.

Comment: I have come across a problem when testing this. Instances where 'basket_qty' doesn't exist in results causes some later logic to fail. 
I did some reading and found I can use if (!("basket_qty" in result)) { to check if it exists, and thought I could do something like result.add(new ("basket_qty", 0)); to insert it with a zero quantity when it didn't exist at all. 
That caused my scripts to stop running as soon as it got to that line of code.
All the info I've read on array push etc seems to be used when you have an array like a,b,c and you want to add d.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to think time complexity too if you have large lists to merge. May be you could give a try below snippet

```js
const cartqtyArrayHash = cartqtyArray.reduce((acc, prod)=> {
    acc[prod.product_id] =prod;
    return acc;
  }, {});
const result = cartArray.map(cart => Object.assign({}, cart, cartqtyArrayHash[cart.product_id]));
```